# Sitecore Update Center : Download and Install Window Timeout Issue

Tags: sitecore-client, upgrade

While upgrading from 9.0.2 to 9.1 I am using the update center from Control Panel. When I use Download and Install it's unable to complete the download as it times out every time. The popup below closes and nothing is logged in the log files. Here is a screenshot of the popup and N/w info from Chrome:

[image]

[image]

Is there any alternate way to get around this?

Comment: Do you know the file path and name for the download. Perhaps you can go to Sitecore's website to download directly and place the assets in the appropriate 
 directory.

Comment: I am not sure as it doesn't display the name of the file it's downloading. However considering it's upgrade it might be downloading the Sitecore 9.1.0 rev. 001564 (update package for 9.x) package. I downloaded this package but unaware of the next steps as the Sitecore documentation for upgrade states to follow the above process(download and install) which when completes gives you a install option.

Comment: Not sure if Sitecore fixed this issue or if the issue was caused due to the heavy call volume to Sitecore during normal business hours. I was able to successfully download this now without any issues.

Comment: I believe the above issue is now resolved and might have caused due to the heavy call volume to Sitecore API's during normal business hours. I tried it outside business hours and was able to download it without issues.

Comment: I have the same issue it couldn't complete the download after 10%,and The popup closes and nothing is logged in the log files, anyone can help me with that please?

Answer (score 2):

In case you would like to manually download the file and install it, all you need is to download the cumulative update package from dev.sitecore.net (Sitecore 9.1.0 rev. 001564 (update package for 9.x) package), open it with any zip extractor and extract the version of update package that suits your version. Then, in the Update Center, click "install custom update" and provide your package

Comment: this is how I solved this issue as well. We come to conclusion that download speed is not enough for Sitecore to continue.